# ChatBotを作りたいがChatGPTのAPIを使わずに作りたい。

Tags: chatgpt

ChatGPTのAPIを使ってChatBotを作りたいのですがAPIが有料でお金がない学生の私ではとても厳しいためとてもAPIを利用できません。なので前回「APIを作ればもしかすると有料じゃなくなるのではないか？」と思い質問しましたが無理でした。それで思ったのですがもうAPIに近いですがChatBotに質問したとしてChatGPTのサイトに飛び質問した内容をコピペしてさらに回答をコピペするAIを作れば実質無料でChatBotがつくれませんか？どうですか？これはできますかね？

Comment: ChatGPTのAPIを使用しなくても、似たようなChatBotを作れるライブラリでLLAMA2や、ELYZA-japanese-Llama-2-7bなどが使用できると思われます。これらはおそらくお金がかからず開発できるはずです。調べてみると良いと思います。前回の質問の続き...というような内容の本文は良くないので直した方が良いです。

Comment: 本当ですか？調べてみます！！

Comment: これは他のリポジトリとも繋げられますか？

Comment: 「他のリポジトリと繋げる」が一般的な表現ではないので、どのような事を指しているのかが読み取れません。

Comment: 例えばGithubにあるVtuberAIのAI waifuやcomic generator AIとかですね。

Answer (score 5):

> それで思ったのですがもうAPIに近いですがChatBotに質問したとしてChatGPTのサイトに飛び質問した内容をコピペしてさらに回答をコピペするAIを作れば実質無料でChatBotがつくれませんか？

上記のことを人間の手では一つ一つ手動でコピペするのではなく、プログラムを用いて自動的に行うという話で良いですね。そうであれば、できる・できないの問題ではなく、利用規約違反になるため、**やってはいけません。**

このような、Webサイトにアクセスし、そこからデータを取り出すような方法はスクレイピングと呼ばれている方法です。スクレイピングはサービスに多大な負荷がかかる場合があるため、ほとんどのサービスでは利用規約で使用を禁止しています。ChatGPTを含むOpenAI社が提供するサービスの利用規約にも次のように書いています。

https://openai.com/policies/terms-of-use

> ### 2. Usage Requirements
>
> (c) **Restrictions**. You may not ... (iv) except as permitted through the API, use any automated or programmatic method to extract data or output from the Services, including scraping, web harvesting, or web data extraction; ....

(参考訳)

> ### 2. 利用要件
>
> (c) **制限** あなたは、... (iv) 許可されたAPIを通じる方法を除き、スクレイピング、ウェブハーベスティング、ウェブデータ抽出などの自動化またはプログラムによる方法で、本サービスからデータの抽出または出力をしてはいけません。...

---

ChatGPTを使ったChatBOTを作りたいなら、有料のAPIを使用する方法以外はありません。ChatGPT以外でまともな大規模言語モデルのサービスで無料で使える物があるのかはわかりません。Llama 2のようなオープンソースの大規模言語モデルも公開されている物があるので、それをローカル環境で動作させるという方法もあるとは思いますが、3Dゲームがまともに動くぐらいのグラボがないと遅すぎて使いものにならないこともあります。Google Colabを使うというのもありますが、無料版では制限があるので、結局有料のGoogle Colab Proでないとまともに使えないと言う可能性もあります。結局何らかのお金は必要になるかも知れません。

Comment: いやぁそうですよね。これどうしましょう。Llama2をローカルで作動させつつ、たまにGPT3のAPIは何ドルまでなら無料にしてあげるよ的なサイトで使用金を限りなく０に近づけるみたいな感じがいいですかね。